# Multiple Blogs in PyroCMS (or other OpenSource CMS)

Tags: php, codeigniter, content-management-system, blogs, pyrocms

I have been looking round for an open-source CMS framework that I can use as the basis for a few web projects. I used to use Joomla, but I found it to be clunky and out-dated, certainly too complicated for the average user that would be faced with it.

My current project requires a content-managed website, with all the usual stuff, and on the whole PyroCMS seems well suited to the task. However a core requirement of the project is that it contains four blogs. A general one for news relating to news in the client's field and then one each for the three members of the company.

I can't see how to do this as it stands, but I'm sure it must be possible somehow. I'm happy to write a module myself to do it if needs be, but I'm trying to keep the project fairly simple, and I can't be the first person to want to do this!

I'd considered a Wordpress network, but a key requirement is that everything is centralised in one administrator panel.

In summary - is there any way to maintain several blogs using just PyroCMS and addons?

Thanks,
Ian

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are a few outstanding features that have never really been added into PyroCMS as they have never really been needed by anyone with enough interest or ability to add them.

The blog module is VERY basic, but it has always been used by incredibly simple sites. "Mom and Pap" websites, simple "News" sections on corporate sites, developer blogs, etc.

Out of the box it CAN be done, by making a pages for "blog" and a category for each, then use the {pyro:blog:posts number="10"}{title} {summary} {/pyro:blog:posts} tags.

It's not the cleanest solution, but remember that most development on PyroCMS is done by developers finding gaps that need to be filled for client projects. I have a client project coming up soon that requires multiple categories (surprised it took so long!), which would solve this problem perfectly, but until they pay me to work on it I just don't have the time. If you want the feature added in for your job I can help you with it if needs be through giving advice on here, in the forums, on IRC etc, then we can merge it in easily enough.

Comment: Hi Phil, thanks for your answer, I had a feeling that might be the case. I'm tempted to write a new more advanced blog module (I think there might be budget in the project to do it), as I've been caught out doing hacky things before in Joomla. Would you say PyroCMS modules are easy enough to get to grips with, given that I'm a fairly experienced PHP developer (albeit with little to no prior experience with codeigniter)?

Comment: It should be pretty easy yes. Basically you have a frontend and backend controller in each module. Modules are handled by https://bitbucket.org/wiredesignz/codeigniter-modular-extensions-hmvc/wiki/Home + some custom details.php stuff, read on install and cached in the DB. New Blog would be AWESOME! I'll happily make the upgrade script. Are you on GitHub?

Comment: I'm not on GitHub, but I'm not adverse to joining :) I haven't used Git before, but have been using Mercurial, which I believe is fairly similar. Would you advise building upon the basic blog module as it stands, or building a new module?

Comment: The current blog module was written 2 to 3 years ago and has not changed all that much. I wouldn't say that it was terrible, but not great. A fresh start might be what it needs for proper blogging.